# user-edit.php profile options on TABS

Tags: profiles, tabs

I´m looking to show all the profile info in the admin area inside tabs. Actually, I see a lot of info of wordpress and other plugins and is too dificult to edit some information that appears on the bottom. Is there a way to show the profile info in tabs?

Thanks in advance